# Is there a way to check if a user and a pass are valid in gmail in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api

I need to check whether a username and password of a gmail account are valid. How can I do that using python?

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't allow access to Gmail accounts from third-party apps without the consent of the account owner.

This is of course a good idea to keep Google accounts more secure and protect sensitive information.

See: [Google Third-party sites & apps with access to your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521)

Now, there are a couple of options I can think of:

---

**1.** If you are trying to access accounts that you own or that have approved access to your app you could use `smptlib` to start a SMTP(Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) client session.

After you established a connection you can attempt to login to your account and print messages appropriately.

**For Example:**

```
import smtplib

username = "gmailaddress"
password = "yourpassword"

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #smtp settings, change accordingly.
server.ehlo()
server.starttls() # secure connection    

try:
    server.login(username, password)
    print("valid account")

except:
    print("invalid account")
```

---

**2.** Google's API - this option, while it may be more suitable will probably also require authorization and further research. Google has an API for many of it's services and even provides examples. See: [Google API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

An API provides a way for you to interact with with a companies online services securely and the way they were intended.

The limited access to Google accounts may seem exaggerated but that's how your account stays secure :) Good luck!